# Proving $(A \times C) \cup (B \times D) \subset (A \cup B) \times (C \cup D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Question:**

Prove $(A \times C) \cup (B \times D) \subset (A \cup B) \times (C \cup D)$ where $A,B,C,D$ are non empty sets.

**My Attempt:**

$$(x \in A \land x \in C) \lor (x \in B \land x \in D) \implies (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x\in C \lor x\in D) $$

That is as far as I got.

**Question:**

Could someone please tell me if what I have done is correct and/or show what needs to be done?

Comment: You reformulated the problem, so where do you need help to finish? Just consider the cases and check that they fit.

Comment: An element of $A\times C$ or $B\times D$ is a *pair* of elements, $(x,y)$, not a single element.

Comment: To emphasize, an *ordered* pair.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but remember that the Cartesian product of two sets is a set of *ordered pairs*.

Thus you seek to *show*, for any $x$ and any $y$, that: $${(x{\in}A\wedge y{\in}C)\vee(x{\in}B\wedge y{\in}D))}~\to~ {(x{\in}A\vee x{\in}B)\wedge(y{\in}C\vee y{\in}D)}$$

Now go *show* that.